# Расширение блока как Вконтакте(Bootstrap)

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Собсвтвенно вопрос в том как это делается ?
То есть когда сайдбар справа уходит, новостная лента становится на всю ширину блока )
Для верски использую Twitter Bootstrap как основу.

Можете ли привести пример расширения?

Хотя бы наводку дайте )

Answer (score 2):

Я не большой знаток JS но думаю товарищ что-то подобное http://jsfiddle.net/Cone/uCNjB/3/ хочет сделать!

Comment: Приветствую адекватность ,да что то подобное, я как протестирую дам знать.Большое спасибо, а Вы не знаете на чисто CSS такое делается ?

Comment: Нет, Вы не узнаете позицию scroll'а.. А вам нужно менять HTML-разметку, при изменении позиции скорллбара..

Comment: Отловить позицию скролла было бы правильно с точки зрения разработки, но тут как бы на первую загрузку страницы же,далее работает )